# Effect of Longpolling on server

Tags: apache, nginx, long-polling, php

I am currently executing a longpolling script within a while(true) loop. PHP `set_time_limit` is set to 0. There is an apache server with another nginx server proxy-ing to the former one. I am pulling text from a MySQL table via this longpolling script. I want to know if this process is going to hamper server performance. If yes, then to what extent if there are a large number of concurrent users pulling data? Should I put the nginx over php-fpm instead?

Answer (score 1):

Long polling has a few notable server-sided properties

- On a server with dedicated workers, it will block a worker
- On an event-based server, it will not block anything in the server
- In any case it will use one or more sockets, which are also a finite resource
- The PHP interpreter uses dedicated workers, so a PHP instance is blocked for every concurrent poll
- In many installations, PHP instances are limited only by available RAM
- If the polling script is done properly context switches and CPU will remain mostly below the radar

Working from this (and assuming you use a production-grade Apache MPM, not the experimental event-based MPM), switching long-poll processing to Nginx will

- free up some Apache workers, without leading to blockage in (event-based) Nginx
- might increase RAM usage: If run with apache-mod-php5 the PHP interpreter's static RAM footprint will occur only once per process

My recommendation is to do some analysis and profiling first: How many concurrent long-pollers really do run concurrently? Does Apache run out of workers (and you can not easily increase the count)? Can you easily port the long-poll to a completely event-based solution (e.g. node)?

If in doubt, I tend to keep things close together, so if your main app runs inside Apache, moving the long-pollers out needs good arguments to convince me - please understand, that this last part is just personal preference.

Comment: what do you mean by event-based server?

Comment: @nick: An event-based server (e.g. node.js, nginx) does not have a dedicated worker process or thread for each connection